# Closing a userform or window by condition

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I work with a software which has no loading window/picture, so when I run it, I don't know exactly when it starts to run. Though I can monitor the running .exe task in taskmanager I want to create a 'loading window' in VBA to make the loading process more visible. I think a possible way to achieve this is to write a simple macro which contains the shell(.) command and a testing **condition** (eg. if a counter counts to 130 then close the form **automatically** end if). The problem is when I try to use Unload Me, it can not be used unless it is a part of a click event. Here is my code which opens my form:

```
Sub Loadpic()

LPic.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: what are you clicking to close it ? or you want it to close itself automatically?

Comment: I want excel to close it automatically after a while or if a condition fulfils, free from any user interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Unload LPic
Do Events
```

You can find the formname in the properties dialog ( Press F4 when looking at the form)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I've tried this in the code below and I had to click the red close button to make the other part of my code ( the for loop) run.
the unload command doesn't seem to be working or I misuse it :(

`Sub Loadpic()`

`LPic.Show`

`For i = 1 To 10`

`Debug.Print i`

`Next i`

`Unload LPic`

`End Sub`

Comment: I've tried it. Still have to use close button. Here is the code in the module:

`Sub Loadpic()`

`LPic.Show`

`For i = 1 To 10`

`Debug.Print i`

`Next i`

`Unload LPic`

`DoEvents`

`End Sub`

Sorry for the code, I don't know how to put line breaks in the comment.

Comment: is there code in the userform?!  i assume now there isnt .  forget the whole thing and just add  unload me into the userform itself  -  right click on the userform and click view code

Comment: no, it's in the module, I deleted `Unload LPic` `DoEvents` from the module and put only the `Unload Me` command into the userform, and got the following message: Compile error: invalid outside procedure

Comment: Private Sub LPic_Initialize()
 Unload Me
End Sub

Comment: thanks, the error disappeared, my problem remains the same though :(

Comment: Well brute force worked as always :D, Steven, thanks for your patience, here is the final code: 

`Sub Loadpic()`

`LPic.Show Modeless`

`DoEvents`

`For i = 1 To 1400`

`Debug.Print i`

`Next i`

`Unload LPic`

`End Sub`